# Bash Script that lists numbers 1-1000 sequentially with odds being in yellow, even in green, and primes in blue

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, primes

Clearly this is a class assignment. I have been toying with it for a couple days now.  I easily got the odd and even aspect to work just fine, but I am continuously having issues with the primes.

This is odd/even and it works

```
  #!/bin/bash
  for i in $(seq 1000)
  do
    if (($i % 2));then  #even
        echo -e "\e[32m$i\e[0m"  #green

    else  #odd
        echo -e "\e[33m$i\e[0m"  #yellow

    fi
  done
```

This is for odd/even/prime and I cannot get it to work.

```
  #!/bin/bash
  for i in $(seq 1000)
  do
    if (($i % 2));then  #even
            if
                    ($i -eq factor {2..1000})
                            echo -e "\e[34m$i\e[0m" #blue
            else
                    echo -e "\e[32m$i\e[0m"  #green
            fi
    else  #odd
            if
                    ($i -eq factor {2..1000})
                            echo -e "\e[34m$i\e[0m" #blue
            else
                    echo -e "\e[33m$i\e[0m"  #yellow
            fi
    fi
  done
```

This is just my latest attempt. I have tried a couple different ways and non work. A little help would be appreciated. Maybe I am doing it completely wrong, maybe I'm close, but I spent a good amount of time researching this and can never seem to apply it to my script.

Comment: Have you read the Prime Number check pseudo-code? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode

Comment: No, I am dissecting it now and going to try to apply it. Thank you.

Comment: `($i -eq factor {2..1000})` this is supposed to be pseudocode? It's a command "($i" expanded run with arguments `"-eq"` `"factor"` `"{2..1000})"`.

Comment: `if (($i % 2))` means _if `$i` mod 2 != 0_  and this is true for non even numbers (odds) but you have marked in the comments just the opposite.  Check your tests, as you probably are applying the primality test to the wrong set of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic approach of using `factor` to determine if a number is prime is OK, but a little work is needed to extract the information.  This modified version of the original code is one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A glob pattern to match 'factor' output that has at least two numbers
# separated by whitespace after a colon (e.g. '30: 2 3 5')
composite_factors_glob='*:*[0-9]*[[:space:]]*[0-9]*'

for i in {1..1000} ; do
    factors=$(factor "$i")
    # shellcheck disable=SC2053
    if (( i > 1 )) && [[ $factors != $composite_factors_glob ]] ; then
        echo -e "\e[34m$i\e[0m" # prime => blue
    elif ((i%2 == 0)) ; then
        echo -e "\e[32m$i\e[0m" # even  => green
    else
        echo -e "\e[33m$i\e[0m" # odd   => yellow
    fi
done
```

The `# shellcheck` comment suppresses a spurious [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) warning.

Comment: Thank you pjh! this is great.  I am a novice when it comes to Linux, scripting, and programming, so I am a little confused by what a glob pattern is. I see that if i > 1 AND factors does not equal the glob pattern then it is prime. How exactly does that work? Thanks again!

Comment: @ender987, see [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for an explanation of glob patterns.  The code assumes that `factor` output for primes looks like '97: 97' (just a single number after the colon) and output for non-primes (except 1) looks like '91: 7 13'  (at least two numbers, separated by whitespace, after the colon).  There are many other, and almost certainly some nicer, ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Prime Number Pseudocode - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode , it's fairly easy to port this to a BASH script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Given an integer as an argument
# return 1 if the number is prime, 0 otherwise
function isPrime
{
    number=$1

    if [ $number -le 3 ]; then
        if [ $number -gt 1 ]; then
            return 1
        else
            return 0
        fi
    elif [ $(( $number % 2 )) -eq 0 ] || [ $(( $number % 3 )) -eq 0 ]; then
        return 0
    fi

    i=5
    while [ $(( $i * $i )) -le $number ]; do
        iplus2=$(( $i + 2 ))
        if [ $(( $number % $i )) -eq 0 ] || [ $(( $number % $iplus2 )) -eq 0 ]; then
            return 0
        fi
        i=$(( $i + 6 ))
    done

    return 1
}
```

It's not necessary to use the `$` with `$var` notation inside numerical expressions, e.g.: `$(( x + 1 ))` is OK, but I leave it there on purpose, as I think it makes the the code's operation more obvious to the non-scripting reader.

BASH functions can't really return a value in the traditional programming sense, it's basically an an exit code sort of thing.  So the "returned" value has to be obtained via `$?`.

```
isPrime $1
primal=$?
if [ $primal -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$1 is prime"
else
    echo "$1 is not prime"
fi
```

Giving the output:

```
$ ./isPrime.sh 7
7 is prime
$ ./isPrime.sh 8
8 is not prime
```

Comment: `So the "returned" value has to be obtained via $?`. You can just `if ! isPrime "$1"` in your code, although that looks misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.

```
# from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392068/check-if-a-number-is-a-prime-in-bash
isPrime() {
    if (( $1 == 2 || $1 == 3 )); then
        return 0  # prime
    fi
    if (( $1 % 2 == 0 || $1 % 3 == 0 )); then
        return 1  # not a prime
    fi
    local i w
    i=5
    w=2
    while (( i * i <= $1 )); do
        if (( $1 % i == 0 )); then
            return 1  # not a prime
        fi
        i=$((i + w))
        w=$((6 - w))
    done
    return 0  # prime
}

isEven() {
    (( $1 % 2 == 0 ))
}


seq 1000 |
while IFS= read -r n; do
   if isPrime "$n"; then
       echo blue "$n"
   elif isEven "$n"; then
       echo green "$n"
   else
       echo yellow "$n"
   fi
done
```

`isPrime` function is just copied from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392068/check-if-a-number-is-a-prime-in-bash) which was the first result in the search `bash how to check for prime number` in google. Fixed it's return value, so it returns 0 (success) if a number is prime, and return nonzero if a number is not prime, and changed to using only arimetic expansions.

As OP understands how to use escape sequences to print colored output on terminals, I just did simple echos for readability.

@edit Fixed a typo in isPrime function /while/s/==/<=/
@edit and of course isEven function should be reversed ...

Comment: Thanks Kamil, this is starting to make sense for me, but its still not working. Not all the blue numbers are prime and such as 995 and 985 and a few others, also he odds and evens are showing reversed colors. Any Ideas?

Comment: @ender987 You are right, sorry, made two small typos there. I have edited the answer.

Comment: great thank you Kamil. This is great, appreciate your efforts